# Build unique columns from sql query into array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

Have been working on this for a while now, have spent hours trawling through old questions and have managed to get to this point so far.

Question is if I change the way my temp data gets recorded into my sql server or if there is a simple solution that someone can come up with to convert to correct JSON data.

I have a table with 5 columns 
ID - Primary auto increment - not used but to give unique database entries
node_id - one of 5 at this stage DS18B20 sensors labelled Sensor 1-5 
payload - temperature reading from sensor 
date - date 
time - time

The below code works because I have limited it to the data from Sensor 1 only

I need to somehow run a loop to auto create as many columns as there are sensors and then have it load the array with the "payload" data for each unique sensor.

The time and date while stored individually for each node_id is always the same due to the way my python code is structured, it reads all sensors first and records all sensors discovered in one database entry - therefore 20 sensors would also mean 20 datetime entries.

The end result would be to have multiple sensors as individual lines on my google linechart using the same datetime as the X axis, temperature reading on the Y axis.

Now I can manually fill out the rest of the code to create the columns but I am still at a loss on how to correctly create the JSON

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("FAMP", "dbuser", "dbuser", "templog");

$query = '
        SELECT payload, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(" ", date, time)) AS datetime
        FROM temp where node_id="Sensor 1" ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
        ';

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
        array(
                'label' => 'Date Time',
                'type' => 'datetime'
        ),
        array(
                'label' => 'Sensor 1',
                'type' => 'number'
        ),
//      array(
//              'label' => 'Sensor 2',
//              'type' => 'number'
//      ),

);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        $sub_array = array();
        $datetime = explode(".", $row["datetime"]);
        $sub_array[] = array(
                                "v" => 'Date(' . $datetime[0] . '000)'
                        );
        $sub_array[] = array(
                                "v" => $row["payload"]
                        );
        $rows[] = array(
                                "c" => $sub_array
                        );
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Sample table data:

```
"id","node_id","payload","time","date" 
"1","Sensor 1","21.1","12:21:47","2022-04-15"   
"2","Sensor 2","22.1","12:21:47","2022-04-15"   
"3","Sensor 3","20.7","12:21:47","2022-04-15"   
"4","Sensor 4","19.3","12:21:47","2022-04-15"   
"5","Sensor 5","22.5","12:21:47","2022-04-15"   
"6","Sensor 1","21.3","12:30:02","2022-04-15"   
"7","Sensor 2","22.3","12:30:02","2022-04-15"   
"8","Sensor 3","20.8","12:30:02","2022-04-15"   
"9","Sensor 4","19.4","12:30:02","2022-04-15"   
"10","Sensor 5","22.8","12:30:02","2022-04-15"
```

Desired output data:

```
[ ['DateTime',        'Sensor 1', 'Sensor 2', 'Sensor 3'], 
['Date(1650093662000)', 22.2,       23.2,        23.5],   
['Date(1650093603000',  22.3,       23.4         23.6], ]);
```

Have managed to get a working solution to show correct chart.
Just need to get code dynamic so it will automatically scale to the amount of sensors I am calling.

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("FAMP", "dbuser", "dbuser", "templog");

$query = "SELECT unix_timestamp(concat_ws(' ', a.date, a.time)) AS datetime, a.payload AS 'Sensor 1', b.payload AS 'Sensor 2', c.payload AS 'Sensor 3' from `temp` as a
inner join temp as b on a.time = b.time and a.date = b.date
inner join temp as c on a.time = c.time and a.date = c.date
where a.node_id = 'Sensor 1' and
b.node_id = 'Sensor 2' and
c.node_id = 'Sensor 3' order by a.date, a.time";


$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
        array(
                'label' => 'Date Time',
                'type' => 'datetime'
        ),
        array(
                'label' => 'Sensor 1',
                'type' => 'number'
        ),
        array(
                'label' => 'Sensor 2',
                'type' => 'number'
        ),
        array(
                'label' => 'Sensor 3',
                'type' => 'number'
        ),

);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        $sub_array = array();
        $datetime = explode(".", $row["datetime"]);
        $sub_array[] = array(
                "v" => 'Date(' . $datetime[0] . '000)'
            );
        $sub_array[] = array(
                "v" => $row['Sensor 1']
            );
    $sub_array[] = array(   
                "v" => $row['Sensor 2']
            );
    $sub_array[] = array(   
                "v" => $row['Sensor 3']
                        );
        $rows[] = array(
                                "c" => $sub_array
                        );
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart()
        {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);

                var options = {
                        title:'Temperature Sensor Data',
                        legend:{position:'bottom'},
                        chartArea:{width:'95%', height:'65%'}
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
        }


   </script>
   <style>
   .page-wrapper
   {
        width:90%;
        margin:0 auto;
   }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="page-wrapper">
        <br />
        <h2 align="center">Display of 94 Broughton Street Temperature Sensors</h2>
        <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>

   </div>
  </body
</html>
```

Comment: First you must get all the unique dates as a derived table and then join it 5 times to the main data table. Then you will be able to get 5 columns of data per each date.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves. …

Comment: … If the question doesn't depend on SQL (i.e. the DB interaction portion is working as intended), then it should be replaced with sample data within the code that isn't working as intended (to minimize the sample code).

Comment: On the subject: is an SQL or PHP solution desired? Note that since either could be used, asking which one to use is subjective, and thus wouldn't be suitable for this site (one of the pitfalls with this issue). If you're not sure which, you could post two separate questions, one for an SQL solution and one for a PHP solution, cross-linking the questions to explain the difference (and thus why they're not duplicates, another pitfall). …

Comment: … Before doing that, you'd need to ensure there aren't existing questions that cover the same territory, e.g.: "[Pivot Table with Dynamic](//stackoverflow.com/q/54872240/90527)" (converting one column into multiple columns, so multiple rows become one row is known as a "pivot" operation). This is made difficult as too many people don't check for duplicate questions or write unclear questions.